# How to Serialize a matrix

Tags: android, serialization

Hey when I try to save a object to internal storage. I keep on get error NotSerializableException saying I need to Serialize matrix so can I go about doing that ?

Comment: if you getting NotSerializableException you need to make your matrix class serializable fx.: implement some interface ... google will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which Matrix-class you are talking about, if it is the [android.graphics.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html), you'll have to use `getValues()` to get an array of the contained values and Serialize that, then on loading the data back you create a new Matrix and call `setValues()` with the array as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Replace android.graphics.Matrix with this class, which is Serializable:

```
public class SerializableMatrix extends Matrix implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    float[] f = new float[9];
    this.getValues(f);
    out.writeObject(f);
}


private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    float[] f = new float[9];
    f = (float[]) in.readObject();
    this.setValues(f);
}
}
```